# How to set default value if not set in filter_var_array

Tags: php

How to set the default value of an array element if the key doesn't exist using `filter_var_array()`:

```
var_dump(filter_var_array([], [
    "page" => [
        "filter" => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
        "options" => [
            "default" => 1,
            "min_range" => 0
        ]
    ]
]));

//output: [ 'page' => null ];
```

Any idea set to `[ 'page' => 1 ]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key must exist in the array in order to be validated (pass or fail).  The third argument `add_empty` which defaults to `true` adds missing keys as `NULL` to the return value.  This doesn't help as it would be nice to add it with the default value.

A common approach is to create the required keys that don't exist as `NULL` or preferably the default value.  Your `$array` will overwrite the `$required` when they have common keys:

```
$array = [];
$required = ['page' => NULL];  //or 'page' => 1
$array = array_merge($required, $array);

var_dump(filter_var_array($array, [
    "page" => [
        "filter" => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
        "options" => [
            "default" => 1,
            "min_range" => 0
        ]
    ]
]));
```

The only other way that I can see to do this is to add empties as `NULL` and then validate again to get the default value (not ideal):

```
$array = [];

var_dump($array = filter_var_array($array, [
    "page" => [
        "filter" => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
        "options" => [
            "default" => 1,
            "min_range" => 0
        ]
    ]
]));

var_dump(filter_var_array($array, [
    "page" => [
        "filter" => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
        "options" => [
            "default" => 1,
            "min_range" => 0
        ]
    ]
]));
```

Adds key with `NULL` value:

```
array(1) {
  ["page"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Adds the default value:

```
array(1) {
  ["page"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, and now I understand. Element must exist!

Answer (score 0):

I just add an array data and it worked

```
$data['page'] = NULL;
var_dump(filter_var_array($data, [
    "page" => [
        "filter" => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
        "options" => [
            "default" => 1,
            "min_range" => 0
        ]
    ]
]));

?>
```